# Reverse a string without using standard functions

Tags: c++, string, recursion, reverse

I recently got asked this during an interview.  As a recent graduate, and only been programming about 2 years (all school work), I was at a loss.  I had a vague idea, but I'm sure I failed it.  This is what I'd written:

```
string Reverse(string word, string reversed)
{
    if(word.length() == 0)
    {
        return reversed;
    }
    else
    {
        string temp;
        reversed = word.substr(0,1) + reversed;
        temp = word.substr(1);
        Reverse(temp, reversed);
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

Now that I'm home, I'm testing it, and the return is only the first letter in the input.  I'm vaguely familiar with the concept of recursion, but I'm obviously failing at this.  Any help/pointers/suggestions are very much appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT:
Following Dennis Meng's post, I've made the following change:

```
string Reverse(string word, string reversed)
{
    if(word.length() == 0)
    {
        return reversed;
    }
    else
    {
        string temp;
        reversed = word.substr(0,1) + reversed;
        temp = word.substr(1);
        return Reverse(temp, reversed);
    }
}
```

Now, I get the proper return value.  Thank you so very much.

Comment: What's the question? Did they ask you to solve it w/ recursion?

Comment: Why is a `Reverse` function taking *two arguments*?

Comment: The answer I'd have been looking if I asked this question in an interview would be one which involved constructing a new string using a reverse iterator pair.   I'm not going to give you a full answer - you can look that up yourself.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes He's using an accumulator.

Comment: @Marko: I think that would be considered "with standard functions".

Comment: What is considered "standard functions"? std::string or C-style string?

Comment: I'd assume functions from either.

Comment: Missed that title.  However, I wonder whether using stl iterators would count?  I also wonder how one is supposed to get the length of the string without calling a function on it?

Comment: @Marko: We can only guess, but for me this question has some sense if you use only C code (what is the purpose of such exercise?) or C++ STL code (then what is without "standard functions"?).

Comment: @SChepurin it's a trivial 1-liner with STL.  In fact, so trivial, I doubt you'd even write a function for it!  The question would be altogether more challenging if you had to perform the operation in-place!

Comment: @Marko: It is no more trivial than a "standard" interview question "What is polymorphism?".

Comment: That's a surprisingly hard question to answer well.  Arguably a good test communication skills as well as of theoretical knowledge.

Comment: @Marko: Interview questions don't have to be "hard to answer". Interview is not supposed to be a competition because usually you need a good candidate for a job, not a champion.

Comment: @SChepurin very much so - there is often the case for having the diligent, and more junior completer-finisher rather than another star-developer with a huge ego in your team, and sometimes budget constrains what you hire.  There's nothing wrong with expecting to mentor new team members either  - but it depends very much on the project environment and having somebody to do it. 
What you never want is a liability that you then later have difficult firing for not being terribly good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going wrong is in here:

```
    else
    {
        string temp;
        reversed = word.substr(0,1) + reversed;
        temp = word.substr(1);
        Reverse(temp, reversed); // <-- Here's your problem
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

You know that the call should return the correct answer, so why not just return that? In other words, what if you did

```
    else
    {
        string temp;
        reversed = word.substr(0,1) + reversed;
        temp = word.substr(1);
        return Reverse(temp, reversed);
    }
}
```

instead? The specifics of why your code was only returning the first letter involves pass-by-reference/pass-by-value; because of the pass-by-value stuff, you never actually used what was done in the recursive calls. (You just made the call and threw away what it returned.)

Comment: Thank you very much!  That little change did it.  Is this type of question commonplace in interviews?  In my classes, my instructors always emphasized "not reinventing the wheel".  I'm wondering if I was given the wrong mindset.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's a pretty common interview question to start things off, make sure you have the basics, etc. Your instructors are right in saying that you shouldn't reinvent the wheel, but it's good to know how the wheel was invented, and interviewers want to know your thought process more than the answer anyway.

Comment: (Also, the other guys are right in saying that there are much better ways to do this, but I'd say on the fly in an interview question this approach is perfectly fine.)

Comment: Having seen my original response, even though it didn't get the proper return value, what would you think as an interviewer?  Just trying to gauge a potential call back.  I felt the rest of the interview and test went fine.  Just got caught on this.

Comment: Well, I'm probably not the best person to ask for what an interviewer would say, but if I were interviewing you and saw this code, I'd see that you at least have a rough understanding of recursion, point out that there was a bug, and encourage you to fix it. Once it's fixed, then I'd see if you can do this recursively without the accumulator, and finally see if you can do the iterative solution.

Comment: Yes - although when I'm interviewing I ensure candidates who can't answer this kind of question get screened out well before that point so I don't waste my time. 

I tend to prefer setting more open-ended or ambiguous questions involving a bit of design. For me the process of getting to an answer is much more important than the answer itself.

Candidates with a weak understanding of pointers is something that is surprisingly common - even for intermediate and senior candidates!

Comment: @Marko Okay, I suppose if the job involves writing C/C++ then knowing pass-by-reference/pass-by-value is a big thing, and candidates need to understand it well. I was commenting on programming interviews in general.

Comment: @Marko:  Well, it was step two of the process.  First was an over the phone, second was this skills test.  I'm only applying for an entry-level position that showed it needed 0-2 years experience.  I just want to learn more.

Comment: @Renrael I've tended to use a 15-20 question multiple-choice pre-screening test.    A question such as this might well figure in it, but the focus would probably be on spotting what was wrong with an implementation.   Where I pitch the pass/fail point depends on the role I have to fill. 
The best advice I can give is to get lots of practice of writing software. Participating in an open source project - and particularly one that has lots of participants and high likelihood of peer review - is a great way to go about it.   Candidates who have done this definitely impress me.

Comment: @Dennis Meng - I was actually replying to Renrael there!

Comment: Ah okay, I see what you were replying to. Sorry about that :P

Comment: I'll add to this, that number of years experience tends to correlate very badly with technical ability and understanding of the fundamentals.  Seemingly a lot of people muddle through a career as a software developer with neither and get away with it!

In the UK it's pretty much illegal to ask for X years of experience in a job specification anyway, so I don't  (it could be construed as age discrimination)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using recursion here.  it's really unnecessary:

```
string Reverse(string word)
{
    string reversed = "";

    if(word.length() == 0)
    {
        return reversed;
    } 

    for (int i = word.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        reversed = reversed+word[i];
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

Comment: "`sizeof(word)`" -- nonononononoNO!

Comment: @ewok `sizeof(word)` does not return the length of the string, but the size of the `std::string` class, which is not what you want. You need to use `word.size()`

Comment: why are you being passed in `reversed`?

Comment: OP was originally using it as an accumulator.

Comment: @DennisMeng: that's because the OP's algorithm required it.  This one doesn't.

Comment: True, but at this point I'd just chalk it up to answerer doing copy/paste and not pruning everything out.

Answer (score 1):

```
string Reverse(string word, string reversed) 
{
    ...
    Reverse(temp, reversed);
```

First of all, you should be passing `word` by const reference, and `reversed` by reference.  When you call the recursive function, you're making a copy of each of those strings, so the outermost function cannot see anything they do.  Another option would have been to assign the result of the recursed function to `reversed`, but then you still have a silly number of string copies everywhere.  So: pass the variables by reference.

Second: There's way easier ways to reverse a string:

```
 string Reverse(string word) //caller should _not_ see my changes, so I pass by value
 {
     for(int i=0; i<word.size()/2; ++i) { //for each letter in the first half
         int otherindex = word.size()-1-i; //find the letter on the other half
         char t = word[i];  //and swap them
         word[i] = word[otherindex];
         word[otherindex] = t;
     }
     return word; //return the result
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is nothing but an array of characters. Generally in this case, you should use an array of characters to explain the algorithm. Here is a better way to do it.

```
void reverse(char* str, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = len -1 ; i < len / 2; ++i, --j) {
         // Swap the values as i and j.
         int temp = str[i];
         str[i] = str[j];
         str[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

If the same question is asked in Java, you have to make sure that you are converting the string to char[] array reverse it and then form a String. This helps in keeping the number of object that are getting created minimal. At least, you should use a StringBuilder.

Comment: There's no need for a StringBuilder in C++; strings are mutable.  And since they implement `operator []`, you could effectively use this very same algorithm with it, except that you no longer need to pass `len` cause the string already knows it.  :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution (similar to one already posted).
But now I see that this solution is not ok for you, since it uses std stuff.

```
std::string reverse(std::string const& character_queue_) {
    using namespace std;
    string result;
    if(!character_queue_.empty()) {
        vector<char> character_stack;
        std::copy(character_queue_.begin(),character_queue_.end(),std::back_inserter(character_stack));
        while(!character_stack.empty()) {
           result.push_back(character_stack.back());
           character_stack.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just to suggest a better way of handling recursion:

String reversal using recursion in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string reverseStringRecursively(string str){
    if (str.length() == 1) {
        return str;
    }else{
        return reverseStringRecursively(str.substr(1,str.length())) + str.at(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout<<"Enter the string to reverse : ";
    cin>>str;

    cout<<"The reversed string is : "<<reverseStringRecursively(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Google "Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm".  :P